# Worklight get device id in version 6.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Trying to get DeviceId using `WL.Device.getID` in version 6.0.2, got error

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no methoed getID`

Using the API as per documentation [HERE](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc%2Fhtml%2Frefjavascript-client%2Fhtml%2FWL.Device.html)

Is it available only in 6.1 onwards version ? Is there a way we can make it work in version 6.0.2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WL.Device.getID` is available starting Worklight 6.1 onwards; this API method is not available in previous versions of Worklight.

To use it, upgrade to Worklight 6.1 or 6.2.